# Getting: Cannot use string offset as an array even after declaring array

Tags: php, arrays, fatal-error

I'm getting the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/a1591957/public_html/sidor/NewSidor.php on line 149

this is row 149:

```
$emp_names_LB[$i][$j] .= "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value=\"\">-------</option>";
```

this is the whole loop this row is in:

```
$emp_names_LB = array();

 for ($i=0;$i<=$num_of_pos;$i++) {
     for ($j=0;$j<=6;$j++) {
          $emp_names_LB[$i][$j] = "\n\t\t\t\t\t" .
           "<select name=\"WorkersDay" . $j . "Shift" . $i . "\">";
          $emp_names_LB[$i][$j] .= "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t" .
           "<option value=\"none\">&nbsp;</option>";
          for($x=0;$x<=($num_sent_sidor - 1);$x++){
              $emp_names_LB .= "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t" .
               "<option value=\"" . $sent_sidor_emp[$x]["id"] . "\">" .
                $sent_sidor_emp[$x]["FirstName"] . 
                " " . $sent_sidor_emp[$x]["LastName"] . "</option>";
          }
          $emp_names_LB[$i][$j] .= "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t" .
           "<option value=\"\">-------</option>";
          for ($x=0;$x<=($num_no_sidor-1);$x++) {
              $emp_names_LB[$i][$j] .= "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t" .
               "<option value=\"" . $no_sidor_emp[$x]["id"] . "\">" . 
                . $no_sidor_emp[$x]["FirstName"] . 
                " " . $no_sidor_emp[$x]["LastName"] . "</option>";
          }              
         $emp_names_LB[$i][$j] .= "\n\t\t\t\t\t</select>";
     }
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's with all the newlines and tabs? They don't mean anything in HTML and make your code very hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

On this line (roughly line 147 or there abouts)

```
$emp_names_LB .= "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t" .
```

You are treating `$emp_names_LB` like a string which performs an implicit type conversion, preventing you from further multi-dimensional array access.

You probably meant to use `$emp_names_LB[$i][$j]` instead.